# How to set the value of a cell based on several other cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an overall status cell of a set of cells with status colors in them. The options are Green, Amber, or Red. Basically, if all of the cells are Green, the overall status cell is set to Green. If any one of them are Amber, then the overall status cell is Amber. Same goes for Red, with Red being the most severe. If there are a mix of Red and Amber and Green statuses, the overall status should be Red. I need to do this with cell values and not just conditional formatting colors. The cells need to actually say Green, Amber, or Red.

How do I go about doing this in Excel with VBA or just with base Excel if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your status colors are in the range, `A1:A10`. Adjust for your case.

Enter the following formula in a cell where you want the overall status...

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("red",A1:A10,),0),"Red",IF(IFERROR(MATCH("amber",A1:A10,),0),"Amber",IF(IFERROR(MATCH("green",A1:A10,),0),"Green")))
```